# Wrong output in comparing floats

Tags: awk, bc, floating-point

I'm trying to compare two floats in bash and something is going wrong. Here is the code sample based on solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8654191/1652217)

```
num1=0.502E-01
num2=0.01
echo $num1'>'$num2 | bc -l
echo $num2'>'$num1 | bc -l
```

I expect the output of `1` for first echo and `0` for second echo, but instead I get `0` for the first and `1` for the second. What is wrong with this input? How to get consistent comparison of these floats?

Comment: Where did you read that `bc` supports exponent notation?  Not in the standard or in the `bc` man page as far as I can see. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/bc.html

Comment: Is there a way to get comparison of these floats in shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` can certainly do float comparisons if called from your shell script.

```
num1=0.502E-01
num2=0.01
awk -v a="$num1" -v b="$num2" 'BEGIN{print(a>b)}'
1
awk -v a="$num1" -v b="$num2" 'BEGIN{print(b>a)}'
0
```

Comment: Great. This I believe should solve my issue